# Add Memcahed service to symfony2

Tags: symfony, memcached, yaml

Services:

```
memcached:
    class: Memcached
    calls:
      -[addServers,[%memcached.servers%]]
```

Parameters:

```
 memcached.servers:
        - { host: 127.0.0.1, port: 11211 }
```

When I try this code I get error

```
Parameter "calls" must be an array for service "memcached" in
 ...Resources/config/services.yml. Check your YAML syntax
```

I try to put even inline but error is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my configurations:

<kbd>config.yml</kbd>

```
memcached:
    class: Memcached
    calls:
        - [ addServer, ['%memcached.host%', '%memcached.port%'] ]
```

In my config.yml the minus symbol under calls in about the s instead of the l in your case (see [in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#optional-dependencies-setter-injection) also).

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you @Matteo , problem was because I tried to call array from parameters.yml there was some syntax error. I tried your solution and it's worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your YAML is invalid. It should be:

```
  - [addServers,[%memcached.servers%]]
```

at the end of the block

Comment: End of the wich blok? If you mean on end of memcached service blok it is on end.